# MATLAB:Getting different results when running my program at different times

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on Speckle Noise reduction in Ultrasound Images using MATLAB R2013. I have designed 10 basic filters and trying out hybrid combination using these filters. When I run my program I get different results at different time for the same input image, no other input parameters were changed. When I ran my program at 1.17 am, I got the PSNR = 74.5424 and when I ran the same program at 1.21 am, I got PSNR = 75.04. Why this is happening ?

If it is coming different values at every time I run my program, how could I conclude on a single value ? Please help. I have attached the screenshot below, see the values of SNR, PSNR, Beta and Speckle Index.

[image: problem with my program]

Comment: Some example code would be useful. Do you use any random variables or mex files? In case of mex files, you can have memory or/or pointer issues.

Comment: no mex codes.. i will give the codes..i am adding speckle noise in preprocessing of image.. using imnoise command. will this be the reason for my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> J = imnoise(I,'speckle',v) adds multiplicative noise to the image I, using the equation J = I+n*I, where n is uniformly distributed random noise with mean 0 and variance v. The default for v is 0.04.

So you are using random Noise, therefore your Result is not deterministic. (A predictable RNG would be a bad one...)
If you want deterministic results, you could calculate the noise beforehand save it in a mat file and apply it from the file each time.

According to the MATLAB help,the equation is `J = I+n*I`

> where n is uniformly distributed random noise with mean 0 and variance v. The default for v is 0.04.

You can calculate such n for every pixel and store it as a heightxwidth double matrix --let's call that N. After you loaded that, apply the noise by evaluation:

```
Img2 = Img .* (1+N);
```

Comment: How to calculate the noise beforehand save it in a mat file ?